# Как сделать форму отправки изображения на AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Нужно сделать форму отправки изображения в которой не нужно при нажатии кнопки "загрузить" переходить в файл upload.php.
С текстовыми полями это у меня получается, но как подобное сделать с загрузкой файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С PHP я помогать не буду но чтобы остановить отправку формы можно использовать `return false`

```js
function xhr(method, file, asyncr) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  //доп действия
}
xhr.open(method, file, asyncr);
xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="xhr('GET', 'upload.php', true); return false">
  <input type="file" name="imgfile"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: А как можно узнать загрузилось ли изображение??? Типа пока происходит загрузка выводим надпись "загрузка...", а когда файл загрузился виводим надпись "загружено".???